# spring cloud unable to route to internal application

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am using spring cloud to route application but unable to do so below are the details

**Gateway configuration**

```
   port: 8080
debug: true
spring:
   application:
      name: cloud-gateway
   cloud:
      gateway:
         discovery:
            locator:
               enabled: true
               lower-case-senstive: true
      routes:
      -  id: product-composite
         uri: localhost:7000
         predicates:
         -  Path: /product-composite/**
```

**eureka:**

```
   instance:
      hostname: localhost
   client:
      registerWithEureka: false
      fetchRegistry: false
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
server:
   port: 8761
   waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
   response-cache-update-interval: 5000
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'
```

**Product Composite Service*** (I am trying to call)

```
   port: 7000
spring:
   application:
      name: product-composite
eureka:
   client:
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
         initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds: 5
         registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
      register-with-eureka: true
      fetch-registery: true
   instance:
      leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 5
      leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 5
```

***Path***

```
@RestController
public class ProductCompositeServiceController {

    @GetMapping
    public String getString() {
        return "Hello grom product CompositeController";
    }
}
```

Can you help? If needed I can provide more details
Note: if `product-composite-servcie` is called without eureka I am getting response but with eureka I am getting

```
404 Resource not found
```

**Edit**
Below is the stacktrace I am getting so far:

```
2020-06-24 22:22:05.252 DEBUG 38876 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.r.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : [63939523-1] Mapped to ResourceWebHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"]
2020-06-24 22:22:05.255 DEBUG 38876 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.r.resource.ResourceWebHandler      : [63939523-1] Resource not found
2020-06-24 22:22:05.273 DEBUG 38876 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [63939523-1] Resolved [ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND] for HTTP GET /product-composite/
2020-06-24 22:22:05.281 DEBUG 38876 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [63939523-1] Encoding [{timestamp=Wed Jun 24 22:22:05 IST 2020, path=/product-composite/, status=404, error=Not Found, mess (truncated)...]
2020-06-24 22:22:05.299 DEBUG 38876 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [63939523-1] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

I also tried to add path as

```
routes:
      -  id: product-composite
         uri: localhost:7000
         predicates:
         -  Path: /product-composite/**
         filters:
         - RewritePath: /product-composite/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Comment: It looks like your service responds to "/" but your route is "/product-composite" which would 404. You need to modify the path using `StripPath`, `SetPath` or `RewritePath`.

Comment: @spencergibb, Thank you for your comment. but seems like I am missing some small detail here. Tried to Add your mentioned suggestions but it seems like not working

Comment: adding `spring.webflux.base-path=product-composite`  to product-composite-service solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a path in your controller. Try

`@GetMapping("/product-composite")`